# Top, Left Aligning a Single Image Using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am trying to upload an image on our webpage (https://www.palousebicycle.org/team.html) so that the person's face isn't cut off, while keeping the others the same (it is the last image).

I tried inline html:

```css
#staff2 {
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.staff img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 228px;
  height: 228px;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.staff figure {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nick {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  align: top, left;
}
```

```html
<img "#nick" src="pictures/nick.jpg" alt="Nick" align="left,top">
```

as well as assigning an image #id (#nick) and using the CSS properties "align", "left", and "top".

I also tried using a frame on the picture to move it top-left, but I couldn't get the image in the right place to not show the frame.

We are a small nonprofit, and it's been awhile since I wrote the webpage, so forgive me for being a bit rusty, and probably not asking the question correctly.  Please let me know any other information or files I can post, and thank you so much for any help!  I really appreciate your time and assistance!

Comment: You need a new image.  Pushing the image down and to the right from the upper left corner will only introduce new problems.

Comment: Thank you!  I will ask our employee for a new picture!  That seems like a good solution.  I appreciate your response!

Comment: This is what your image would have looked like if you had shifted it, https://imgur.com/a/EjVrUaz. If there was a lot more photo above and to the left of the individuals face, nudging this one image would have worked.

Comment: Yes!  That's what it looked like when I tried putting a frame around it.  Maybe if I get tricky, I could upload it as a png with a transparent background?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, this is a more accurate representation of what I was getting at, https://imgur.com/a/Pn1Rlp6. You'll notice that nudging the image inside the circle will leave empty areas. You can circumvent this by zooming in like one of the solutions below does. But the downsides to that are that the image will become pixelated and, to prevent empty areas within the circle, might be zoomed in too much compared to other images and might not be centered enough. The legitimate solution is to find an image with a central focal point with enough content around it that it doesn't create empty areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest that you simply crop the image to a 228px by 228px square with the person centered appropriately in the image. That would give you the most control in terms of the way the image is cropped.

If you want to do it with css, you can do something like this:

```css
#nick {
  background-image: url(https://www.palousebicycle.org/pictures/nick.jpg);
  background-size: 300%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 228px;
  height: 228px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div id="nick"></div>
```

Displaying the image with the `background-image` css property instead of with html `<img>` tag allows you to better control the way it is cropped. In this case, I just added a `background-size: 300%` which sized the background appropriately to fit the face in the circle.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks great.  I tried to hamajang it into our existing html and css, and I couldn't get it to format like your example, but I will try to re-write the page with css (remove the html figure and image tags) to get it more controllable, per your suggestion.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must replace ("#nick") to (id="nick") in img component.

Comment: This could not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).